# error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2Int'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this problem in my cave generation script, this is the line

```
Vector2Int nextPoint = passage[passage.Count - 1] + (Vector2Int)(dir * connectionLength);
```

How I do solve it?

I never had this error so I dont know how to solve it, it will probably an error very easy to solve but I'm just beginning with unity. I'm expecting someone that says me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Vector2Int.FloorToInt(Vector2 t)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.FloorToInt.html) to do the conversion, I don't believe there is an explicit conversion defined from `Vector2` to `Vector2Int`. In case you prefer rounding instead of flooring the value, you can also use [`Vector2Int.RoundToInt(Vector2 t)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.RoundToInt.html)

---

Your code would look like this:

```
Vector2Int nextPoint = passage[passage.Count - 1] + Vector2Int.FloorToInt(dir * connectionLength);
```

Comment: There is indeed no implicit conversion the same way there is also none for `float` -> `int`, only the other way round. Worth mentioning that there is also [`FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.FloorToInt.html) which would be closer to the usage of `(int)someFloat` .. depending on OP's needs

Comment: You are right, I missed that in the docs, I will switch it!

Comment: @derHugo Also, I never wrote "implict conversion" but "explicit conversion" from `float` to `int` which [does exist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#explicit-numeric-conversions).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `Vector2` and `Vector2Int` are two different types. `Vector2` can store float values while `Vector2Int` cannot.

---

Therefore you need to Round the `dir` Vector2 (as it seems) to the nearest integer value. For this, You can use [`Vector2ToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html).

Overall your code should look like this:

```cs
Vector2 nextPoint = passage[passage.Count - 1] + (dir * connectionLength);
Vector2Int nextPointInt = new Vector2Int((int) nextPoint.x, (int) nextPoint.y);
```

Assuming that the value types are:

```cs
private Vector2 dir;
private int connectionLength;
private List<Vector2Int> passage;
 ----- OR -----
private List<Vector2> passage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
 // Convert the Vector2 to Vector2Int.
 vector2IntValue = Vector2Int.FloorToInt(vector2Value);
```

Your Final Code :

```
 Vector2Int lengthVal = Vector2Int.FloorToInt(dir * connectionLength);
 Vector2Int nextPoint = passage[passage.Count - 1] + lengthVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just solve it thank you, but I have another problem my script doesn´t create a map it creates a block of tiles.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).